# Add column to a table if not exist

Tags: sqlite

I have a problem to add a new column to a SQLITE table if this column is not already exist.

I have try with this code but i don’t know why it wont execute:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mytable' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'mynewcolumn')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN mynewcolumn TEXT    
END
```

I get an Exception error :

> error: near "IF": syntax error

Comment: Removed `(SQLITE)` from title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution i select :

1- I do PRAGMA table_info :

```
pragma table_info(MyTable)
```

This command gives all the informations about all the columns of the table. each row correspand to the information of a column.
This commande return an output table with 4 columns : **cid**, **name**, **type**, **notnull**, **dft value**, **pk**

2- I read all the rows from **"PRAGMA table_info (MyTable)"**, and i compare the column **"name"** with the name of the column i want to check if exist.

3- If Column exist then i dont do anything

4- but if the column doen't exist then, here i add the column to my table using this commade :

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN NewColumn TEXT;
```

this is work for me, and do the job correctly.

Answer (score 1):

To test whether a column exists, execute [PRAGMA table_info](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) and check if the column name appears in the result.